# How to understand such a complex event $\left((a\cap\grave{b})\cup(b\cap\grave{a})\right)$ in probability?

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of the event $\left((a\cap\grave{b})\cup(b\cap\grave{a})\right)$ in probability?

Comment: I don't know the notation $`$, so I am just going to assume that it is the complementary. If so, it is the event where either $a$ or $b$ is satisfied, but not both

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: You will need to define $\grave{a}$ for us. Did you mean $\overline{a}$?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first part $a\cap b'$ we have members of $a$ not in $b$.  For the second part $b\cap a'$ we have members of $b$ not in $a$.  When we union these two pieces we're asking for the members of the two exclusive groups (exclusive $a$ members on the left, exclusive $b$ members on the right if we're thinking in terms of a Venn Diagram).

Comment: When we union two exclusive sets, we get their combined elements, not their overlap, surely?

Comment: For instance, if $a$ is married people and $b$ is women, we get married men unioned with single women.  That's the set that combines married men with single women, not the empty set.  (Huh, now that example sounds like all sorts of wrong, but you get the idea. :-o)

Comment: @BrianTung Yes you're right, I edited my response